# Classpath exported OK,java Class.class invokes error

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath, set, noclassdeffounderror

executed ok:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/sergio/workspace/teal
```

`Anon.class` resides in `teal` directory

both `java Anon` or `java -cp /home/sergio/workspace/teal Anon`
 invoke classical:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Anon
```

Have I missed something in CLASSPATH declaration?

Answer (score 0):

If the package of your class is `teal`, you should be exporting the classpath "till" the package directory, not into it.

`export CLASSPATH=/home/sergio/workspace/`

To make it more generic, if the package of a class `Bar` is `com.foo` and the directory structure looks like,

```
[+] classes/
[+]    com/
[+]        foo/
[-]            Bar.class
```

You should set classpath till `classes` only.

Comment: I set classpath till "teal" dir and it's executed ok with command:java teal.Anon and

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "." in your classpath.

For Unix this is done with

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/sergio/workspace/teal:.
```

Comment: Then double check your source and class files.